# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'wup_similarity'

Tags: python, similarity

I'm trying to use babelNet instead of wordnet because I have special combined words from the computer science domain, my code is to find similarities for a list of topics (lst).

code:

```
from babelnetpy.babelnet import BabelNet

bn = BabelNet("")

lst = ['artificial_intelligence', "real_time", 'Big_data', "Healthcare",'Fuzzy_logic']


def get_bn_main_sense(synsetid):
        """
        get main sense
        """ 
        return bn.getSynsets(synsetid)[0].mainSense
    
get_bn_main_sense('bn:03890554n')

def get_synset(a_list):
    synset_list = []
    for word in a_list:
        a = bn.getSynset_Ids(word, "en")[:1] #The index is to ensure each word gets assigned 1st synset only
        synset_list.append(a)
    return synset_list

lst_synsets = get_synset(lst)


def bn_syns(given_list): 
    synset_bn = []
    for word in given_list:
        synset_bn.append("bn.[%s]" % word)
    return synset_bn

lst_s_bn = bn_syns(lst_synsets)

def lower(list):
    new_list = []
    for word in list:
        new_list.append(word.lower())
    return new_list


lower_is = lower(lst_s_bn)

def clean(a_list): 
    new_list = []
    for word in a_list:
        b = word.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("bn.synset", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("'", "")
        new_list.append(b)
    return new_list

clean_is = clean(lower_is)


# id of the synset you want to retrieve

artificial_intelligence_Ids = bn.getSynset_Ids("artificial_intelligence", "en")
artificial_intelligence=artificial_intelligence_Ids[0]

real_time_Ids = bn.getSynset_Ids("real_time", "en")
real_time=real_time_Ids[0]

Big_data_Ids = bn.getSynset_Ids("Big_data", "en")
Big_data=Big_data_Ids[0]

Healthcare_Ids = bn.getSynset_Ids("Healthcare", "en")
Healthcare=Healthcare_Ids[0]

Fuzzy_logic_Ids = bn.getSynset_Ids("Fuzzy_logic", "en")
Fuzzy_logic=Fuzzy_logic_Ids[0]


#is_variables
artificial_Intelligence_syn = get_bn_main_sense('bn:03890554n')
real_time_syn = get_bn_main_sense('bn:01258457n')
Big_data_syn = get_bn_main_sense('bn:02063206n')
Healthcare_syn = get_bn_main_sense('bn:00043361n')
Fuzzy_logic_syn = get_bn_main_sense('bn:15130487n')

is_variables = [artificial_Intelligence_syn, real_time_syn, Big_data_syn, Healthcare_syn,Fuzzy_logic_syn]


# wup similarity

def similarity(list1, list2):
    sim_dict = {}
    for syn in list1:
        for sin in list2:
            sim = (syn).wup_similarity(sin)
            if sim >= 0.5:
                sim_dict.update({(syn, sin): sim})
    return sim_dict

b_s = similarity(is_variables, is_variables)
```

I get the error **"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'wup_similarity'"** when I try to run this code to find a semantic similarity for this list (last) !!!

. any suggestions or hints are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The returned values of the function `get_bn_main_sense` are of type string. `str` doesn't have any method named **wup_similarity**. `mainSense` is of type string:

```py
>>> type(bn.getSynsets('bn:03890554n')[0].mainSense)
<class 'str'>
```

I couldn't find any object or class with this method or algorithm in the [**babelnetpy**](https://github.com/jackee777/babelnetpy) library.

[NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) library does have this method but uses Wordnet. Maybe you have confused these two libraries.

Comment: the problem with my list is I can't find some combined words in Wordnet, this is why I used babelnet